# Vue.js generate a .pdf document with complex tables

Tags: vue.js, pdf

I need to add the possibility to generate a .pdf file containing this kind of tables (image attached) in vue.js app. I receive data as JSON and the is no html version of tables shown on the image.

What are my options to achieve the goal ?

Should I first create html version and convert it to .pdf or the is an easier way? Which libraries could I use?

[image]

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. What have you tried so far?

Comment: `Handlebars` to build table template based on JSON data, and `Puppeteer` to generate PDf from handelbars output.